# Filter array of objects by amount property

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to get the `expectedOutput` array, which consists of the objects with the higher amount number. Thanks in advance.

```js
let arr1 = [{name: 'Almendras', amount: 0},{name: 'Nueces', amount: 0}, {name: 'Chocolate', amount: 0}];
let arr2 = [{name: 'Almendras', amount: 2}];

let expectedOutput = [{name: 'Almendras', amount: 2}, {name: 'Nueces', amount: 0}, {name: 'Chocolate', amount: 0}];
```

Im tried by this way:

```js
console.log(arr2.filter(x => x.amount > arr1[x].amount));
```

Comment: Since SO isn't a code writing service, can you post your attempts at getting the expected output?

Comment: sure, ill edit the post

Comment: Just loop over the any one of array and use the index to access corresponding element as well, and built your final array based on your condition. ( believing your array's are of same length and sorted in same order )

Comment: You can use map as in my answer down here

Comment: @sonEtLumiere the problem with your code is filter will return the values from array you're operation on based on condition use map instead and also, you're trying to access the second array with current element instead of index, index is second parameter in filter

Comment: `arr2.filter` you are treating x as an index

Comment: No, the arrays don't have the same length sometimes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the example you gave uses the same index in both arrays, you could map through the first array and index compare the second array and return one or the other:

`var res = arr1.map((v, index) =>  v.amount > arr2[index].amount ? v : arr2[index]);`

If either array can be larger than the other you could find the larger array, loop through it and compare it with the smaller one and add the objects to a new array until you reach the end, and then add the remaining objects from the larger array.

Comment: This only works if both arrays have the same objects.

Comment: "the objects with the higher amount number" - The evidence is that there will be comparable `amount` fields in each array index.

Comment: I edited the question, the arrays sometimes have diferent length

Comment: I updated my answer with how I would solve that problem if either array can be larger then you would need to know which one is larger to do the comparison. In this case I think you could use `map` with additonal edge case checks for truthy values using the larger array, or you could use a normal for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), which provides the index as the second argument to the callback, and use a ternary operator the compare the element at the index in both arrays.

```js
let arr1 = [{name: 'Almendras', amount: 0},{name: 'Nueces', amount: 0}, {name: 'Chocolate', amount: 0}];

let arr2 = [{name: 'Almendras', amount: 2}, {name: 'Nueces', amount: 0}, {name: 'Chocolate', amount: 1}];

let res = arr1.map((curr,idx)=>curr.amount > arr2[idx].amount?curr:arr2[idx]);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know that both arrays are sorted according to the inner object `name` key, then the other answers which compare indices are probably the best method. However, if you know that the arrays could be unsorted, here is a potential solution.

***Note:** If you are dealing with arrays of varying sizes, you would have to filter or iterate through both arrays.*

```js
let arr1 = [{name: 'Almendras', amount: 0}, {name: 'Nueces', amount: 0}, {name: 'Chocolate', amount: 0}];

let arr2 = [{name: 'Almendras', amount: 2}, {name: 'Chocolate', amount: 1}, {name: 'Nueces', amount: 0}];

let expectedOutput = [{name: 'Almendras', amount: 2}, {name: 'Nueces', amount: 0}, {name: 'Chocolate', amount: 1}];

let actualOutput = arr1.map((ele1) => {
  let ele2 = arr2.find((e) => e.name === ele1.name);
  if(ele2) {
    if(ele2.amount >= ele1.amount) {
      return ele2;
    }
  }
  return ele1;
});

console.log("actual: ", actualOutput);
console.log("expected: ", expectedOutput);
```